# Json Scala Play2

Tags: scala

With Scala play2 I have a json list and I have this format, and I want to get a json of one element of the list that has a `idPatient = "test"`.  How can I do this with scala play2?

```
 {
      "msg_type": "i",
      "correspondent": {
        "idCorrespondent": "eee",
        "profil": "e",
        "firstName": "test",
        "lastName": "test",
        "mobile": "test"
      },
      "patient": {
        "idPatient": "test",
        "firstName": "ahmed",
        "lastName": "test",
        "birthdayDate": "test"
      },
      "result": {
        "idResult": "12",
        "dateOfResult": 1507,
        "msg_type": "xxxxx",
        "msg_raw": "xxxx1"
      }

}
```

Comment: i just blocked i dont have any idea where i start .

Comment: http://queirozf.com/entries/working-with-json-data-on-the-play-framework-for-scala-examples

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson

Comment: thx bro i wil try